# Concert schedules in Vienna

Tags: tickets, austria, events, vienna, salzburg

I will be in Vienna and Salzburg in September-October and, like every other visiting tourist, would like to attend a concert or opera.  However, checking the sites of the [Wiener Philharmoniker](https://www.wienerphilharmoniker.at/en/konzerte?v=30-08-2023&ia=f&iv=f&sm=f), [Wiener Staatsoper](https://www.wiener-staatsoper.at/en/season-tickets/events-tickets/) etc, at time of writing (March) the schedules are only published until August at the latest.

**When do ticket sales for concerts in Sep/Oct begin**?

Comment: Likely to be in May for the season starting in Sep 2023, since eg https://www.wiener-staatsoper.at/en/service/ticket-sales/buy-tickets-202223/ tickets for September and October 2022 went on sale on May 16th, 2022. Thereafter, tickets go on sale two months in advance on the first of each month for the entire month.

Comment: Traveller post answers, not comments, even if not yet 100% sure. Next time I might delete the comment.

Comment: @Willeke I’m just quoting from the website and only about the one location/concert option.  I’ll post it if someone with local / better knowledge doesn’t answer more comprehensively, I prefer not to give an incomplete answer that might well attract downvotes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Opera Tickets

[The Wiener Staatsoper website](https://www.wiener-staatsoper.at/en/service/ticket-sales/buy-tickets-202223/) states that:

> ### BUY TICKETS 2022/23
>
> Tickets for September and October 2022 are on sale since 10am on May 16th, 2022. Thereafter, tickets will go on sale two months in advance on the first of each month for the entire month. For example, on September 1st, for the whole of November or on October 1st, for the whole of December.

In addition,

> You can pre-order tickets for performances that are not yet on sale. You can find more information under PRE-ORDER.
>
> ### PRE-ORDER
>
> Ticket pre-orders for performances from November 1st until the end of season 2022/23 are available since May 16th.

Tickets can be bought [online](https://www.wiener-staatsoper.at/en/season-tickets/events-tickets/), by phone by calling +43 1513 1513, or in person. Pre-orders can be made [online](https://www.wiener-staatsoper.at/en/season-tickets/events-tickets/), in writing, or in person.

Comment: Thanks, but that information is for the 22/23 season ending June 2023.  Although I presume the dates will be similar for the 23/24 season.

Comment: 2023 update: this year ticket sales started on May 2nd, and a week later there was still plenty of availability across all the dates & concerts we were interested in Sep/Oct.